# Transposing not quadratic matrix to another

Tags: c++, eigen

I try to *transpose* from one `MatrixX*` into another (not quadratic but with correct dimensions). However the best I could find is the `Transpose< Derived > ::transpose()` function.

Is there even a call which puts the result into an already allocated Matrix instead of allocating a new one?

EDIT:

Actually I was using `Eigen::Map` on top of the Matrix.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<std::uint8_t, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> matrix_type;
typedef Eigen::Map<matrix_type> map_type;

const map_type src ( src_ptr , width , height );
      map_type dest( dest_ptr, height, width  );

map.transposeInPlace();
```

Using `transposeInPlace()` triggers an assert in `Derived& DenseBase<Derived>
  ::lazyAssign(const DenseBase<OtherDerived>& other)`.

Comment: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=88932 look at this thread, may be it will help with this assert. I never faced with this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Eigen::Map` on top of a Matrix indeed results in an assert, since it seems like `transposeInPlace` is not possible yet for `Eigen::Map` (AKA a bug).

Luckily for me, using regular `::transpose` was fine, since `Eigen` uses late assigning of data.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `transposeInPlace()` function

Here is the documentation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html

> For in-place transposition, as for instance in a = a.transpose(),
>   simply use the transposeInPlace() function:

```
MatrixXf a(2,3); a << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
cout << "Here is the initial matrix a:\n" << a << endl;
a.transposeInPlace();
cout << "and after being transposed:\n" << a << endl;
```

---

UPDATE: As Zeta mentioned in comment, matrix object should be resizable - this is always true for all MatrixX* objects.

Comment: @Zeta: What are the criteria for being _resizeable_?

Comment: @LCIDFire: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html#TutorialMatrixAssignment. However, `dynamic` matrices are resizeable per default, as long as you use only `MatrixX` and not one of the compile-time constant sizes you shouldn't get any non-resizeable matrix.